# Android imei problems (I think)

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, imei

Hello and thank you all in advance
I had problems when I start my galaxys3, I have researched think is the IMEI

But if I press * # 06 # if I get my IMEI just that with a forward slash before the last 2 digits

Also I have a yellow box with information

I have internet, but I can not connect my phone to any network
and when I turn tells me that this mode makes and me off the internet, you just have to turn it to functions

An image which shows me the phone: http://postimg.org/image/qnj9eavln/

Both the IMEI as factory folder are empty, the'm seeing with "ES file explorer"

PS: If I get negative points for doing wrong and know that you can correct.
Thanks to all

Comment: Flashing the stock ROM can restore the IMEI, I believe I did this back in the day on my original SGS.  That icon looks like a SIM error so first you might try removing the SIM, rebooting, and then inserting it and rebooting again.

Answer (score 0):

If the suggestion above doesn't work, try flashing a stock firmware via Odin. Brought my imei back back then. After that you can root again and do all that stuff. I recommend installing one of the efs tools from the playstore to backup the efs folder.